# All lines of Python file are highlighted in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Every time I save my code in Sublime Text 2, all of the lines end up highlighted as seen below. It's pretty annoying, and I would love to disable it, but I'm not sure what triggered it in the first place or what to Google. Any ideas?

[image: Sublime Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

The cause is SublimeLinter plug-in and its PEP-8 filter

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Your code does not conform PEP-8 style guide:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Writing code that matches the PEP-8 style guide is generally a good idea as it has been well-vetted by the community as being a generally productive and efficient coding style. You may find that following it allows others to comprehend your code better. Of course, any code that parses and runs correctly might be 'good enough' for your purposes.

Comment: It complains about the indentation being tabs? That's stupid.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm just starting out with Python, so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Minitech: Using hard tabs is not recommended by PEP-8. The filter just follows this policy. http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/

Comment: Here are instructions how to configure Sublime Text 2 to have sane tab policy http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Configure_sane_tab_and_whitespace_policy_and_other_settings